# import widget in kivy file

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

I created some custom widget.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


class ExampleWidget(Widget):
     Builder.load_file("kv/example.kv")
```

kv/example.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<ExampleWidget>:
    Label:
        text: Example
```

Than I want to create another widget with example widget. Like this:

kv/second.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<SecondWidget>:
    ExampleWidget:
```

But I got this error

```
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <ExampleWidget>
```

Kivy can't find my custom widget, so how I can import it to another kivy file?

Comment: could you show a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import it using following syntax (assuming that `ExampleWidget` is defined in `example.py` file and you have `__init__.py` in your directory):

```
#: import ExampleWidget example.ExampleWidget

<SecondWidget>:
    ExampleWidget:
```

Described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#special-syntaxes).

Comment: You dont even have to do that. The example he shows works fine for me.